# How do I convert a char from a string to a double and more?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, console-application

I need a program that tells me all the [disarium numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disarium-number/) smaller than a user defined number between 10 and 1.000.000 (if possible between 10 and infinite).
Even though vs doesn't show any errors in the editor, when I run it, it shows this error message: "System.InvalidCastException: 'Invalid cast from 'Char' to 'Double'.'" at one of the

```
calculation = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[0]), 1.0);
```

I've tried other methods to convert the characters to doubles, but they give the same or other error messages or convert them wrong.
Furthermore, I'm almost certain that I can use a more compact method than using a switch statement to determine the amount of digits the number has (maybe something that reads the length of the number?) but don't know how.

```
//prints out all the disarium numbers lower than a user defined number
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //assigns the variables
    string number , strI;
    double calculation = 0;

    //asks the user for string number
    Console.WriteLine("Give a number between 10 and 1.000.000. This program will tell you all the disarium numbers lower than the given number.");
    number = Console.ReadLine();

    //calcules all the disarium numbers lower than string number
    for (int I = 10;I < Convert.ToInt32(number);I++)
    {
        strI = Convert.ToString(I);
        switch (strI.Length)
        {
            case 1:
                calculation = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[0]), 1.0);
                break;
            case 2:
                calculation = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[0]), 1.0) + Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[1]), 2.0);
                break;
            case 3:
                calculation = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[0]), 1.0) + Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[1]), 2.0) + Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[2]), 3.0);
                break;
            case 4:
                calculation = Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[0]), 1.0) + Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[1]), 2.0) + Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[2]), 3.0) + Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[3]), 4.0);
                break;
            case 5:
                Console.WriteLine("...");
                break;
            case 6:
                Console.WriteLine("...");
                break;
            case 7:
                Console.WriteLine("...");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        //Prints out all the desarium numbers below string number
        if (calculation == Convert.ToDouble(I))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(I + " is a disarium number.");
        }
    }

    //Keeps the command line from closing
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close the program.");
}
```

If it isn't clear enough.
I basically make a new variable with the value of i from the for loop, but as string (I do this so I can go trough the number character by character)

```
strI = Convert.ToString(I);
```

Then I determine the amount of digits the input number has by using a switch statement.

After that, I make a variable that is the 1st char of i fraction 1, the 2nd char of i fraction 2... until it reaches the amount of digits

```
Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[0]), 1.0) + Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[1]), 2.0)...
```

lastly I compare i with the outcome of the calculation

```
if (calculation == Convert.ToDouble(I))
```

If the variables match, it is a disarium number.

Thanks in advance!

~ Emanuel

Comment: Converting a char to a double makes no sense. What would the char be? You need multiple characters to represent a double. Otherwise, the best you can get from a single character is a one-digit integer.

Comment: @ itsme86 If I'm correct, Math.Pow needs 2 doubles to work though.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToDouble_System_Char_ the docs explicitly say that ConvertToDouyble(char) will throw. Now you could ask - so why implement it - ask MSFT

Comment: @itsme86. '4' converted to a double does not seem an impossible dream. I would expect to get 4.0 out of it.

Comment: @itsme86 also note that convert.todouble(bool) works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Convert.ToDouble(strI[0].ToString())
```

That will fix your calculations so that they do not throw exceptions. Doing the floating point comparison at the end is potentially problematic though due to how floating points are stored with rounding. I would recommend that you cast each result of Math.Pow back to int/long before adding them. If int/long is not big enough, you may need something like BigInteger (System.Numerics namespace).

Also, that switch statement can be replaced with something like...

```
strI = Convert.ToString(I);
calculation = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < strI.Length; i++)
{
    calculation += Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[i].ToString()));
}
if (calculation == Convert.ToDouble(I))
...
```

Comment: As an aside, the Intellisense for Convert.ToDouble(char) says "Calling this method always throws InvalidCastException". I question why the method even exists in that case.

Comment: Thanks! that's the main problem down :). I'll keep the question on unsolved for the hope of answers to my other problems for now. Did I understand right that Convert.ToDouble converts a string to a double and strI[0] alone is an integer?

Comment: I made an edit to mention a couple of other items. I think I covered everything now. strI[0] alone is a char not an integer. I suspect the reason that char is not supported is because a char is stored as an integer in memory. So '0' would have a value not equal to 0, but rather equal to 48 (I think that's the ASCII code at least). It would be unclear in implementation is the char '0' should me zero or forty-eight. ToString() changes it to be a string which is always interpreted as zero.

Answer (score 0):

Final working code:

```
//prints out all the disarium numbers lower than a user defined number
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //assigns the variables
    string number , strI;
    double calculation;

    //asks the user for string number
    Console.WriteLine("Give a number between 10 and 1.000.000. This program will tell you all the disarium numbers lower than the given number.");
    number = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("");

    //calcules all the disarium numbers lower than string number
    for (Int64 I = 10;I < Convert.ToInt64(number);I++)
    {
        calculation = 0;
        strI = Convert.ToString(I);
        for (int i = 0; i < strI.Length; i++)
        {
            calculation += Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(strI[i].ToString()), Convert.ToDouble(i) + 1.0);
        }

        //Prints out all the desarium numbers below string number
        if (Convert.ToInt64(calculation) == I)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(I + " is a disarium number.");
        }
    }
}
```